# How to get Optimized RTL of a C Program?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have dumped the RTL generated as intermediate using "-fdump-final-insns" flag in compilation of a C Program using gcc but i need the optimized version of it, i.e. the resultant RTL after optimization phase of compiler. How can i get it ?

Example - 
Register Transfer Language (RTL)

```
(insn 14 12 15 (nil) (set (reg:CCZ 17
    (compare:CCZ (mem/f:SI (plus:SI (reg/f:SI 54 virtual-stack-vars)
            (const_int -4 [0xfffffffc])) [0 i+0 S4 A32])
                (const_int 99 [0x63]))) -1 (nil)
            (nil))
```

Optimized RTL -

```
(insn 14 12 15 (nil) (set (reg:CCZ 17 flags)
     (compare:CCZ (reg/v:SI 61 [ i ])
         (const_int 99 [0x63]))) -1 (nil)
 (nil))
```

Comment: (@Paebbels: `gcc` itself calls this "RTL": 'Dump the final internal representation (RTL) to *file*.' Would the tag [tag:rtl] need adjusting? Discuss on [meta]?)

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can use flags:

```
gcc foo.c -da -dp -fdump-tree-all-raw-lineno
```

Where:

`-da` produce all `RTL` dumps

`-dp` annotate the assembler output with a comment indicating which
patterns and alternatives are used.

`-fdump-tree-all-raw-lineno` Enables showing line numbers for statements.

This will create about 167 files, each of them means different stages of GIMPLE and RTL passes, optimizations and so on.
Here is simple explanation is what's going on:

https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/courses/cs715-09/gcc-rtl.pdf

Look at last two number 306 and 307, there is the final, optimized phase of compiler before parse it into assembler.

```
foo.c.306r.final
foo.c.307r.finish
```

You can also use flags `-S` with `-dA`
Where:

`-S` produces assembler output

`-dA` annotate the assembler output with miscellaneous debugging information

and in `foo.s` you can view a connection between `RTL` and assembler code.